# .Net Chart control with logarithmic scale on the X-axis

Tags: telerik, radchart

For a project we are using the Telerik RadChart control to display a graph on a website. At the moment the X-axis follows a normal scale but we would like to change that to a logarithmic scale. As far as we can tell the control does not allow that.

Does anyone know of an alternative that would support this?

TIA,

David

Example of what we would like to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

"Unfortunately the current version of RadChart does not support logarithmic X-Axis. We have already logged such a request in our public issue tracking system, you can find it here, however, taking a decision for implementing a certain feature depends on multiple conditions including complexity, existing features impact, demand rate, etc. It is not yet in our immediate plans, still, I would encourage you to use the above link to vote and track the issue."

Regards,
Nikolay
the Telerik team

Taken from [here, as it was posted this month.](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/chart/does-radchart-support-x-axis-logarithm-scale.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll make sure to vote for this issue.

Comment: You can also mark this answered/upvote it if it answers your question so others who come here will know it it the correct response. Glad I could help.